# tikzposter cannot display accented characters from the T1 font

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

The `tikzposter` has an issue in displaying accented characters from the T1 font. For example, `\DJ` (Đ) is displayed as a black square.

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this. Thank you in advance for your help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Title}
\author{\DJ}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tikzposter` class loads the obsolete (and deprecated) `aer` fonts.

Add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{Title}
\author{\DJ}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!